# Change the borderStyle of the UISearchBar text field

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uisearchbar, uiappearance

I'm looking for a way to get a `UISearchBar` with a different background and text color, and no border.

I already did this :

```
[[[self.searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setAlpha:0.0];
UITextField* searchField = nil;
for(int i = 0; i < self.searchBar.subviews.count; i++) {
    if([[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) { //conform?
        searchField = [self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
if(searchField) {
    searchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:242.0/255.0 blue:210.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    searchField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:98.0/255.0 green:65.0/255.0 blue:48.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    searchField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
}
```

But I'm looking for a way to change the `borderStyle` of the `UISearchBar`'s text field. I also want to delete the magnifier button.  Is it a way to do theses modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching the view hierarchy for the search bar, you could use the appearance API. Have a look under ["Customizing Appearance" in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I tried doing this with UIAppearance using `[[NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField") appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];`, but it doesn't appear to work. Did I miss something?

Comment: @BrandonFosdick There's no such thing as a `UISearchBarTextField`. And instead of `NSClassFromString`, call `appearanceWhen..` directly on the class.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you can use this:

```
let txtField = UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
txtField.borderStyle = .none
```